# dictionary lookup on Python 2.7 vs 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary, dictview

This came up in a nitpick discussion about the prefered style for iterating over dictionary keys if you need to apply some test to the value. I was comparing the performance of `[k for k in d if d[k] == 1]` against `[k for k, v in d.items() if v == 1]`.

Looks like dictionary lookups are more expensive in Python 3.4:

```
$ python -m timeit -n 1000000 \
  -s 'd={k:v for v, k in enumerate("abcdefghijhklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")}' \
  '[k for k in d if d[k] == 1]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 2.17 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 1000000 \
  -s 'd={k:v for v, k in enumerate("abcdefghijhklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")}' \
  '[k for k, v in d.items() if v == 1]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 3.13 usec per loop

$ python3.4 -m timeit -n 1000000 \
  -s 'd={k:v for v, k in enumerate("abcdefghijhklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")}' \
  '[k for k in d if d[k] == 1]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 3.25 usec per loop

$ python3.4 -m timeit -n 1000000 \
  -s 'd={k:v for v, k in enumerate("abcdefghijhklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")}' \
  '[k for k, v in d.items() if v == 1]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 3.05 usec per loop
```

Are lookups more expensive in Python 3.4 compared to 2.7 and can you explain why?

Comment: I can't reproduce similar results on my machine. If anything, the Python 3 `.items()` should be slightly faster as it doesn't build an intermediate list.

Comment: Note that the types are significantly different: for Python 2 you've got a dictionary mapping bytestrings to fixed-width ints, while for Python 3 you're mapping Unicode strings to arbitrary-precision ints.  It could be that hashing a Unicode string is slower than hashing a bytestring, or that comparisons between long integers are slower than comparisons between fixed-width integers.  I couldn't say for sure that that's where the timing difference comes from, though.

Comment: @SimeonVisser honest question: you can't reproduce because the test is flawed, because you don't have both versions or because you got different results? :-)

Comment: Different numbers that don't suggest 3 is slower than 2 here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that lookups are more expensive<sup>1</sup> in Python 3.4 than 2.7, but that `dict.items()` is cheaper. That's because `dict.items()` is a rather different beast in the two versions of the language:

```
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 03:19:35) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type({}.items())
<type 'list'>
>>>
```

```
$ python3.4
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 08:07:42) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type({}.items())
<class 'dict_items'>
>>>
```

In Python 2, `dict.items()` constructs and returns a list, whereas in Python 3 it returns a [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), and it turns out that iterating over this dynamic view into the dictionary is faster than constructing a list and then iterating over that.

Although `dict.items()` doesn't return a dictionary view in 2.7, it *is* possible to get one with [`dict.viewitems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems), with similar performance benefits. Repeating your test, this time with `viewitems()` included, I get:

```
$ python2.7 -m timeit -n 1000000 \
  -s 'd={k:v for v, k in enumerate("abcdefghijhklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")}' \
  '[k for k in d if d[k] == 1]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 3.38 usec per loop
```

```
$ python2.7 -m timeit -n 1000000 \
  -s 'd={k:v for v, k in enumerate("abcdefghijhklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")}' \
  '[k for k, v in d.items() if v == 1]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 4.33 usec per loop
```

```
$ python2.7 -m timeit -n 1000000 \
  -s 'd={k:v for v, k in enumerate("abcdefghijhklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")}' \
  '[k for k, v in d.viewitems() if v == 1]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 3.27 usec per loop
```

As regards the discussion that prompted your investigation, I'd say that the `d.items()` or `d.viewitems()` approach is more explicit, and therefore more pythonic, but that's really more an aesthetic choice than anything else.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except inasmuch as Python 3.x is, as a general rule, slower than 2.x, but that's the price of progress ...